# move subfolders based on date last modified

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to find MS Excel/VBA code to move all subfolders with lastdatemodified < date -30 to a different folder.

Like this (but obviously not this)

```
foldertomove = subfolder 
folder = main
newfolder = archive

for each subfolder in main
if subfolder.datelastmodified < date - 30 then
move subfolder to archive
end if
next
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please refer [Copy and Move files and folders](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm). It covers movement of files related to date. You have to use File System Object (FSO) .

Comment: hi @skkakkar, i found that but it only covers moving one folder at a time. it also covers moving multiple files at a time but not folders. i tried (valiantly, I feel) to adapt both to my needs but could not figure it out. could someone please help?

Comment: Do you want to move folder and its files and there is only one level of nesting of sub-folders i.e. there are no folders hierarchy. If there is folder hierarchy it will require recursive looping. Further please note that I always     prefer copying instead of moving. While moving unexpected errors can occur if there are files with same names at the destination folders or there are directory permissions problems. In that situation co-relating what has moved and what has not requires rigorous checking. Copying is safe as your original folders are intact and can be deleted after successful move.

Comment: @skkakkar yes, the subfolders I want to move have subfolders in them as well. copying sounds fine to me. from my main folder i want to move (or copy) all subfolders (including everything inside of them, all subfolders and files) to an archive folder if it has not been modified in the past 30 days). thanks!

Comment: I shall look into it a couple of hours later.

Comment: I am still working on it. It is a bit complex program and is taking more time then I have estimated. Pl bear with me.

Comment: @skkakkar thank you so much! it amazes me you're willing to help to this extent, I can't tell you how much it is appreciated!

Comment: I have finished working on the program and I shall post my answer very soon. I have clearly detailed out its features and pre-requisites. Hope this program meets your requirements to a great extent. If it is so do not forget to accept the answer by ticking below lower triangle on the left side of Answer.

Comment: @skkakkar thank you so much! i will go through this today and get back to you.

Comment: I shall at a later stage incorporate a routine to create folder structure automatically through Excel VBA. I shall inform you when it is finished. In the initial tries there were problems which need to be resolved. I shall be too happy, if my knowledge gained so far is useful to someone else.

Comment: I look forward to your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Sub CopyFolders_Recursively()

```
Dim strFolder As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim myResults As Variant
Dim lCount As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get the directory from the user
'With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'.Show

'If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
'user cancelled
'strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
'End With

strFolder = "D:\testing\" '<<change

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
'the variable dimension has to be the second one
ReDim myResults(0 To 5, 0 To 0)

' place make some headers in the array
myResults(0, 0) = "Filename"
myResults(1, 0) = "Size"
myResults(2, 0) = "Created"
myResults(3, 0) = "Modified"
myResults(4, 0) = "Accessed"
myResults(5, 0) = "Full path"

'Send the folder to the recursive function
FillFileList objFolder, myResults, lCount

' Dump these to a worksheet
fcnDumpToWorksheet myResults

CleanUpList

If Range("A2").Value = "" Then GoTo tidyup

AddFolders

Move_Folders

tidyup:

Cells.Delete

Range("A1").Select

'tidy up
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub FillFileList(objFolder As Object, ByRef myResults As Variant,       ByRef lCount As Long, Optional strFilter As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim objFile As Object
Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
Dim fsoSubFolders As Object
Dim lpath As String

Dim Fdtdiff As Integer

'load the array with all the files
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If InStr(objFile.Path, "~Archive") = 0 Then 'don't get files from the   archive folder (assumes the archive folder is a subfolder of the folder from which you're moving the other subfolders

    lCount = lCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve myResults(0 To 5, 0 To lCount)
    myResults(0, lCount) = objFile.Name
    myResults(1, lCount) = objFile.Size
    myResults(2, lCount) = objFile.DateCreated
    myResults(3, lCount) = objFile.DateLastModified
    myResults(4, lCount) = objFile.DateLastAccessed
    myResults(5, lCount) = objFile.Path
    'Fdtdiff = DateValue(Now) - DateValue(myResults(3, lCount))

    'If Fdtdiff > 30 Then
        'lpath = Replace(objFile.Path, "my_dir", "~Archive")
        'objFile.Copy lpath
    'End If

End If

Next objFile

'recursively call this function with any subfolders
Set fsoSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoSubFolders
FillFileList fsoSubFolder, myResults, lCount
Next fsoSubFolder

End Sub

Private Sub fcnDumpToWorksheet(varData As Variant, Optional mySh As Worksheet)

'since we switched the array dimensions, have to transpose
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) '<<change

Cells.ClearContents

    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(varData, 2) + 1, UBound(varData, 1) + 1)) = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

    .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CleanUpList()

'sort most recent files to the top so when we remove dupes we'll be left with the most recent one
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Sort.SortFields.Clear '<<change sheet name
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D65536") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:F65536")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'remove parent folder from path we'll check later
Columns("F:F").Replace What:="D:\testing\", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False '<< Change

'remove file name, leaving just the folder we want to move
Columns("F:F").Replace What:="\*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

'we just need one!
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$AZ$65536").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=6, Header:=xlYes '<< remove dupes of folders to move

Set Rng = Range("D1:D100") '<< change if you know it will be less or more than 100
For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If cell.Value > Date - 30 Then '<<only keep it if more than 30 days (or whatever you want)
        cell.Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next

On Error Resume Next
Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub AddFolders() 'we'll archive by year within the archive subfolder

Set Rng = Range("D2:D100") '<< change if you know it will be less or more than 100
For Each x In Rng

If x.Value <> "" Then

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir "D:\testing\~Archive\" & Format(x.Value - 30, "yyyy") '<< Change
    On Error GoTo 0

End If

Next x

End Sub

Private Sub Move_Folders()
'This example move the folder from FromPath to ToPath

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String

Set Rng = Range("F2:F100") '<< change if you know it will be less or more than 100
For Each x In Rng

    If x.Value <> "" Then

        FromPath = "D:\testing\" & x.Value  '<< Change
        ToPath = "D:\testing\~Archive\" & Format(x.Offset(0, -2).Value - 30, "yyyy") & "\" & x.Value '<< Change
        'Note: It is not possible to use a folder that exist in ToPath
        'We created subfolders by year earlier so we can archive by year now

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        FSO.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Objective of this program is to Copy Folders, Sub-Folders and Folders
  within Folders along with files contained in them. It could be any type of the file PDF, Text, Word, Excel etc.
- This program will only copy Files which are 30 days older from
  Current Time. User can adjust this date or between two dates as per
  his requirements.
- When program is run File Picker Dialog will open and allow user to
  chose the folder to be archived.
- It is very important that an **Empty Directory Structure** with same
  folder structure as parent folder to be archived has is created.
  Presently VBA code for this step has not been incorporated in this
  program. Simplest way is to copy paste folder and then delete files
  in various folders and sub-folders manually. It is one time exercise
  so long as parent directory structure remains the same. Any changes
  in the parent directory structure are also to be incorporated in the
  Archive folder also.
- Program will also output Directory and File Paths on a separate
  workbook of the parent directory being archived. If it is not
  required then relevant portions of the program can be commented out.

Snapshot of output is placed below.
[image: Directory Listing]

Further improvements in this program shall be endeavoured based on feedback and help of experts.
Code is placed below.

```
Sub CopyFolders_Recursively()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim myResults As Variant
    Dim lCount As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Get the directory from the user
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        'user cancelled
        strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    'the variable dimension has to be the second one
    ReDim myResults(0 To 5, 0 To 0)

    ' place make some headers in the array
    myResults(0, 0) = "Filename"
    myResults(1, 0) = "Size"
    myResults(2, 0) = "Created"
    myResults(3, 0) = "Modified"
    myResults(4, 0) = "Accessed"
    myResults(5, 0) = "Full path"

    'Send the folder to the recursive function
    FillFileList objFolder, myResults, lCount

    ' Dump these to a worksheet
    fcnDumpToWorksheet myResults

    'tidy up
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub FillFileList(objFolder As Object, ByRef myResults As Variant, ByRef lCount As Long, Optional strFilter As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    Dim fsoSubFolders As Object
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim lpath As String

    ToPath = "C:\Archive\"
    Dim Fdtdiff As Integer
    'load the array with all the files
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        lCount = lCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve myResults(0 To 5, 0 To lCount)
        myResults(0, lCount) = objFile.Name
        myResults(1, lCount) = objFile.Size
        myResults(2, lCount) = objFile.DateCreated
        myResults(3, lCount) = objFile.DateLastModified
        myResults(4, lCount) = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        myResults(5, lCount) = objFile.Path
        Fdtdiff = DateValue(Now) - DateValue(myResults(3, lCount))

        If Fdtdiff > 30 Then
            lpath = Replace(objFile.Path, "my_dir", "Archive")
            objFile.Copy lpath
        End If
    Next objFile

    'recursively call this function with any subfolders
    Set fsoSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoSubFolders
    FillFileList fsoSubFolder, myResults, lCount
    Next fsoSubFolder

End Sub

Private Sub fcnDumpToWorksheet(varData As Variant, Optional mySh As Worksheet)

    Dim iSheetsInNew As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim myColumnHeaders() As String
    Dim l As Long, NoOfRows As Long

    If mySh Is Nothing Then
        'make a workbook if we didn't get a worksheet
        iSheetsInNew = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iSheetsInNew
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)
    Else
         Set mySh = sh
    End If

    'since we switched the array dimensions, have to transpose
    With sh
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(varData, 2) + 1, UBound(varData, 1) + 1)) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, @skkakkar, this really helped me! It didn't seem to copy anything anywhere but I was able to use the list created with your code to rename/move each subfolder. I don't know if this is the most efficient way this could be done but it works. I commented out stuff from your code not needed due to other other stuff I wound up doing. i'll post my answer below. Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe Patrick I am surprised that it did not copy. I only post after thorough testing. It works for me as per procedure outlined checking for dates. Basic thing for this program is identical empty structure should pre-exist. Otherwise it can be modified to create root directory and dump files in a single root folder.

Comment: @Joe Patrick  Please see the snapshot uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r46upj17hyvtp9f/ice_screenshot_20160528-104532.jpeg?dl=0) program is woking fine as per instructions laid out in the program.

Comment: @Joe Patrick  Please see the snapshot uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r46upj17hyvtp9f/ice_screenshot_20160528-104532.jpeg?dl=0) program is woking fine as per instructions laid out in the program. What you have to do is you want to chose a folder in file dialog folder, before running program copy that to c: (change drive in program if you choose other drive). Then rename that folder to Archive and delete all files in Archive and subfolders leaving empty folders. Then run the program. Please make sure that you always exit debug mode if a program encountered problem.

Comment: I'm sure you're right and it was me not your code, @skkakkar. I probably didn't set something up properly. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Joe Patrick I am confused now what you wish to convey. It is a simple matter, If your answer is better than mine then Tick green your answer but if my answer is acceptable to you, please tick my answer with green tick and close the question.

Comment: thanks again, @skkakkar. I feel like i tried to accept my own answer before and it didn't let me so i didn't even try this time. I've done it now and will close the question. Have a good one!

Comment: I don't see a way to close it... I guess accepting an answer does that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a more direct way to get the subfolders needed to be archived:

```
Private Sub Archive_Hotel_Confs()

Sheets("Archiving").Select

Cells.ClearContents

Dim strStartPath As String

strStartPath = "W:testing\" 'ENTER YOUR START FOLDER HERE
ListHCFolder strStartPath

CleanUpList

If Range("A1").Value = "" Then GoTo tidyup

AddHCFolders

MoveHC_Folders

'tidy up
tidyup:

Cells.Delete

Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Last Run").Select

End Sub

Private Sub ListHCFolder(sFolderPath As String)

Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
Dim FSfolder As Folder
Dim subfolder As Folder
Dim i As Integer

Set FSfolder = FS.GetFolder(sFolderPath)

For Each subfolder In FSfolder.SubFolders

    If InStr(subfolder.Name, "~Archive") = 0 Then

        DoEvents
        i = i + 1
         'added this line
        Cells(i, 1) = subfolder
        Cells(i, 2) = subfolder.DateLastModified
         'commented out this one
         'Debug.Print subfolder

    End If

Next subfolder

Set FSfolder = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub CleanUpList()

Dim x As Variant

'remove parent folder from path we'll check later
Columns("A:A").Replace What:="W:testing\", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart,         MatchCase:=False '<< Change

Set Rng = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each x In Rng
If x.Value <> "" Then
    If x.Value > Date - 30 Then '<<only keep it if more than 30 days (or     whatever you want)
    x.Value = ""
    End If
End If
Next x

On Error Resume Next
Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub AddHCFolders() 'we'll archive by year within the archive     subfolder

Dim x As Variant

Set Rng = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each x In Rng

If x.Value <> "" Then

On Error Resume Next
MkDir "W:testing\~Archive\" & Format(x.Value - 30, "yyyy") '<< Change
On Error GoTo 0

End If

Next x

End Sub

Private Sub MoveHC_Folders()
'This example move the folder from FromPath to ToPath

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim x As Variant

Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each x In Rng

If x.Value <> "" Then

    FromPath = "W:testing\" & x.Value  '<< Change
    ToPath = "W:testing\~Archive\" & Format(x.Offset(0, 1).Value - 30, "yyyy") & "\" & x.Value '<< Change
    'Note: It is not possible to use a folder that exist in ToPath
    'We created subfolders by year earlier so we can archive by year now

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FSO.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End If

Next x

End Sub
```